# Why does using the wrong format specifier in C crash my program on Windows 7?

Tags: c, string, gcc, windows-7

My program is as follows;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char string[] = "Gentlemen start your engines!";
        printf("That string is %s characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));
        return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling under gcc, and although it doesn't give me any errors the program crashes every time I run it.  The code seems to be fine from examples I've seen.  It'd be great to know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Should have seen that, I've just started with C and had been playing around with text programs using strings only thus far, so %s just automatically came to mind.

Comment: +1 because I learned that I should have been using %zu all along instead of merely %u or even %d

Comment: If you're using GCC, crank up your errors with `-Wall` or maybe `-Wextra` or maybe `-Werror`. GCC is able to check the format string and warn about incorrect arguments for `printf`-, `scanf`-, `strftime`- and `strfmon`-like functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using incorrect format specifier in `printf()` invokes Undefined Behaviour. Correct format specifier should be `%zu` (not `%d`) because the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`

Note: Length modifier `z` in `%zu` represents an integer of length same as `size_t`

Comment: When did gcc on Windows stop using the Microsoft CRT? I got errors last time I used %zu on MinGW, or is there another gcc version that uses glib?

Comment: @Pete: You shouldn't get any such error. Make sure you are using latest version of MinGW with C99 support.

Comment: Sweet! Any ETA for MingW implementing emulated UTF-8 locale on top of the windows `_wfopen` etc. functions?

Answer (score 8):

You have wrong format specifier. `%s` is used for strings but you are passing `size_t` (`strlen(string)`). Using incorrect format specifier in `printf()` invokes *undefined behaviour*. 
Use `%zu` instead because the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`.

So change

```
 printf("That string is %s characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));
```

to:

```
 printf("That string is %zu characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));
```

Since you are using `gcc` have a look [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output.html#Formatted-Output) for more info what can be passed to `printf`

Comment: Using `gcc` for compilation doesn't necessarily mean that you are using the glibc for executing your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
 printf("That string is %d characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));
```

instead:

```
 printf("That string is %s characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));
```

Comment: one morething, change the variable name "string" to someother. "string" is reserved word.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I used 'string' to throw together a quick program that got string length, as I'm writing a program that detects palindromes and wanted to get a feel as to how I'd do it.  I'll keep in mind not to use it in the future though.

Comment: Syntactically, `string` is not a keyword. It is though, as all names starting with `str`, `mem` or `wcs`, "reserved for future use" as a string function in the `<string.h>` header. (source: ISO C99, 7.26.11)

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem here 
`printf("That string is %s characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));`

put

`printf("That string is %d characters long.\r\n", strlen(string));`
%d because you want to printthe length of str (strlen returns number)

Answer (score 1):

Program crashes because formatting routine tries to access a string at address `0x0000001D` which is the result of `strlen()` where is nothing like a string and likely there's no acessible memory at all.