# Returning a pointer to float changes the address by the time it reaches main function

Tags: c, pointers

**MAIN METHOD**

```
 int x, y;
    printf("Please enter 2 integers separated by a space: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
```

**OTHER METHOD. This is part of the matrix_get function called from the main function**

```
if (key_comp (key, node->key) == 0){
       data_print(node->data);
```

**SOME HEADER FILE**

```
typedef float Data_Item;
```

Ok so when I return the pointer to the Data_Item (it's a float typedef), the address of it changes and so when I dereference it in the main method it becomes null. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
   pdata=&(node->data);
```

changes the value of `pdata`. It is now different from the value returned by `malloc`. The line that makes more sense, that you have commented out, is:

```
   //*pdata=node->data;
```

In the first line, you are assigning `pdata` to be the address of `node->data`. In the commented out line, you were trying to set the value of what `pdata` points to by `node->data`.

You are missing the `return` from two of the branches.

Change

```
if(key_comp (key, node->key) == -1){
      bs_tree_search_h(node->left, key);
}else if(key_comp (key, node->key) == 1){
      bs_tree_search_h(node->right, key);
}
```

to

```
if(key_comp (key, node->key) == -1){
      return bs_tree_search_h(node->left, key);
}else if(key_comp (key, node->key) == 1){
      return bs_tree_search_h(node->right, key);
}
```

Comment: It still crashes when I replaced the above line with the line i commented out. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't see anything from the code you have posted. It's possible that `matrix_get` returns from a different place.

Comment: Sorry I edited my thread with more stuff. I'm just kinda scared my instructor will think I stole code and give me a 0.. ::(

Comment: The last line of `bs_tree_search_h` returns `NULL`. It's possible that you are hitting that line.

Comment: I can guarantee it doesn't hit that line, I already tested that it hits the return statement of bs_tree_search_h with the pointer. I'm not sure if I wrote the matrix_Get function right though?

Comment: Wow thank you, I can't believe I forgot the return statements. Goes to show you I still don't understand basic recursion haha :(

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d", &pdata);
```

should be

```
printf("%f", *pdata);
```

You're trying to be print the address of the pointer instead of the value of the pointer. Trying to print the address with `%d` is undefined. Use `%f` for float. Using the [wrong format specifier invokes undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231898/183120).

The memory you allocated for the pointer gets leaked, since the pointer's value is overwritten by a local variable's address. Instead you should copy the data in the local variable into the memory allocated for the pointer.

```
*pdata = node->data;
```

Comment: Uhh I was just printing the address of the pdata to see if it changed (it did). The printf function has nothing to do with anything, it was for debugging purposes. The address of pdata from the helper function changed when I returned it to the main function.

Comment: Ok so when I changed it to what you said, the program just crashes now. It's because *pdata is undefined I think? Because that pointer points to nothing..

Comment: It's high time you use a debugger!