# Why this program does not print the desired output?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I just know about the %i format specifier from this link

[Difference between format specifiers %i and %d in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf)

and I tried to implement it with this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    long long a,b;

    printf("Input: ");

    scanf("%i %lld",&b,&a);

    printf("Output: %i %lld",b,a);
}
```

%i worked properly but %lld stores a garbage value in variable a.

This is the output of this program.

> Input : 033 033
>
> Output : 27 141733920846
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.443 s
> Press any key to continue.

Can anyone explain, why I am getting the garbage value in variable a?

Comment: you didn't input a %11d , you've input 033\n(and some garbage from previous executions), that were interpreted by the scanf, the faulty here is the formatting in the scanf, and the scanf itself.

Comment: Passing invalid things to scanf is undefined behavior, and %lld is not accepting octal literals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong format specifiers in scanf (or) printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830052/wrong-format-specifiers-in-scanf-or-printf)

Comment: Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231891/995714, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16864552/995714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf` `%i` takes an `int *`, but you're passing `&b`, which is a `long long int *`. This has undefined behavior.

You should be using `%lli`.

The same problem occurs in `printf`: Use `%lli` to print `b`, not `%i`.

You should also check `scanf`'s return value to make sure two values were successfully read.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to fix it in the printf too. I updated my answer with the fixed code and live demo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `%i` for a `long long int` is undefined behavior, so use `%lli` instead.

The same issue persists in the printf statement, too.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    long long a,b;
    int retval;


    printf("Input: \n");

    retval = scanf("%lli %lld",&b,&a);

    printf("Output: %lli %lld",b,a);
    printf("\nRetval: %d",retval);
    return 1;
}
```

Input:

> 033 033

Output:

> Input:  Output: 27 33 Retval: 2

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/2pIsQp)

Note: Always check the return value of scanf. It returns the number of scanned items, which you should test against your expectations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `%d` is supposed to read `"033"` as `33`, like `atoi("033")`.

Comment: @melpomene Can you provide a source for this? I'm pretty sure that its just not a valid input.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.2p12 says `%d` works like `strtol(..., 10)`. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.20.1.4 says digits less than the base (i.e. 0 .. 9) are accepted. It doesn't prohibit  leading zeroes.

Comment: @melpomene I stand corrected then. Interestingly, changing it to %lli only will not make the garbage value go away. currently investigating further on this.